# NHibernate: getting object model with HQL using a join on table

Tags: join, nhibernate, hql

I am having difficult time trying to figure out how to get a mapped object using a join on a table (not mapped table).

Tables:

```
DataForm: (Id, AliasName (FK), ...)
Customer: (Id, ...)
CustomerAliases: (PK AliasName, CustomerId (FK))
```

So aliases are unique for every Customer and Customer may have many aliases.

Code:

```
DataForm.Customer - this is what I need
```

So how do I write the HQL in the getter?
Since CustomerAliases table is just a list of aliases I don't have it mapped to a class but is accessed through  on the Customer. How can I get Customer using AliasName? 
If it was normal SQL I would just do:

```
SELECT * From Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerAliases ca ON ca.AliasName = 'AliasNameProvided'
WHERE ca.CustomerId = c.Id
```

Comment: What do you mean by HSQL? Why don't you map the aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL can only be use on mapped classes. When you leave the mapped area, you need to use SQL which looks exactly like the SQL in your question.

I would map it:

```
class Customer
{
  IList<string> AliasNames { get; private set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
<class name="Customer">
  <!-- ..... -->
  <bag name="AliaseNames" table="CustomerAliases">
    <key column="CustomerId"/>
    <element column="AliasName"/>
  </bag>
</class>
```

query:

```
from Customer c join c.AliasNames n
where n = :alias
```

Comment: So I don't need to use CustomerAlias class with mapping for this to work? That would be just what I was looking for.. I'll try it.

Comment: No, it's just a list of strings. Not sure if it is that easy to make the alias name the primary key.

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I actually already had a list mapped but I didn't know you could join object.Something :)